# How can we find the area of the given highlighted figure?

Tags: geometry, circles, area, quadrilateral

### Problem

---

Given, we have a square ▢ABCD with a side of 2cm. We construct the diagonal and draw a circle tangent to all the 3 sides of the triangle △ABD formed. Then, we divide this circle into 4 equal quadrants. In one of the quadrants, we construct another circle tangent to the 2 sides and one part of the circle. How can we find its area?

It is highlighted in black in the figure given below.

### My Progress

---

All is was able to figure out was the radius of the bigger circle which turned out to be
$2-\sqrt 2$ which is $\approx 0.59$

How can I find its area?

[image: Problem figure]

PS: I would be grateful to anyone who would be able to explain keeping in mind the concepts learned in grade 8th.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get that radius?

Comment: If you were able to figure out the radius of the bigger circle, I would say the steps are similar for the smaller circle.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, exactly that is what I felt. But, I was unable to find any way through it. I did try the same method but it's not right. If the smaller circle was surrounded by a triangle, it was easy. But instead one of its sides is a part of the circumference of the circle. This made it hard for me

Comment: Then if it helps, around the circle quadrant, create a right-angled isosceles triangle with hypothenuse tangent to both circles. What is the leg length of such triangle?

Comment: Well, I did try that too! But, if we draw a hypotenuse tangent to the big circle, we will have to increase the size of the legs as they will not reach that hypotenuse(as seen in the figure). And if we increase, how are we supposed to know how much we increased?

Comment: More importantly, for each circle, what's the distance from the outside right-angle to the tangent point? For the bigger circle, from corner $B$ to the mid-point of the diagonal? For the smaller circle, from the centre of the bigger circle to some point on the bigger circle? Whether the circle is tangent to a straight line ($AD$) or a circular arc no longer matters.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, that you are right.

Comment: @peterwhy I was biased towards straight lines as in triangles as we can use the tangents meeting are equal theory to find the radius of the circles. But, since I had no such straight line for the small circle, I was stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ and $r$ be the radii of the bigger and smaller circles respectively. The required area is $\pi r^2$.

To follow your approach using "the tangents meeting are equal theory", consider the common tangent line of the two circles:

[image: the tangents meeting are equal theory]

$$r + R = \sqrt{R^2+R^2} = R\sqrt 2$$

---

Alternatively, I use the distance from the outside right-angle to the tangent point to calculate both radii:

[image: the distance from the outside right-angle to the tangent point]

$$\begin{align*}
R + \sqrt{R^2+R^2} = R \left(1+\sqrt2\right) &= BM\\
r + \sqrt{r^2+r^2} = r \left(1+\sqrt2\right) &= R
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So, the radius of the small can be derived by the following equation: $r(1+√2) = (2 - √2)$ since $R = 2 - √2$which gives the small radius to be ≈.24 . Am I right?